# Excel VBA, copy text with formatting from worksheet into an Userform

Tags: text, textbox, formatting, userform, worksheet

I need to pull text with formats from a worksheet into the Userform. I am able to pull plain text, but not able to retrieve text with formatting. Could you please suggest a code for that?

***My code***

**Based on the text input in ComboBox2, a corresponding search result will appear in the two text boxes.**

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

If Len(ComboBox2.Text) > 1 Then
   search1
   End If

End Sub
Private Sub search1()
Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer
Dim temp As String

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
count = 0

For X = 2 To lastrow

```
If Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 1) = ComboBox2.Text Then
    TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 2)
    TextBox4.Text = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 3)
    count = count + 1

End If
```

Next X

Comment: add the code you tried so far?

Comment: Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

   If Len(ComboBox2.Text) > 1 Then
   search1
   End If
   
End Sub
Private Sub search1()
Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer
Dim temp As String

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
count = 0

For X = 2 To lastrow

    If Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 1) = ComboBox2.Text Then
        TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 2)
        TextBox4.Text = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(X, 3)
        count = count + 1
                   
    End If

Next X